# SQL Query to list all the tables

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query to display the list of tables in a specific database along with its table type and number of attributes for that table.

For Example,

[image]

Can anyone help me to get it resolved.

Comment: Look into the system tables information_schema.tables and information_schema.columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can query systems tables like that :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,TABLE_ROWS,TABLE_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='DATABASENAME'
```

Change DATABASENAME for your db name. There is many others options you can display, check :

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='DATABASENAME'
```

EDIT : Version with JOIN so we can count columns

```
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME,T.TABLE_ROWS,T.TABLE_TYPE, count(C.table_name) AS COLUMNS_NUMBER
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C 
ON C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND  T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA='DATABASENAME'
GROUP BY C.TABLE_NAME, T.TABLE_SCHEMA,T.TABLE_ROWS,T.TABLE_TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Table_Rows is giving the count of the rows. But I want to get the number of columns in a table. I tried giving table_columns in the query and I am getting the error as "table_columns" is not in field list.

Comment: That's possible joining ``INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS``, updated my message !